# Sublime text 2, windows, bash/cygwin instead of cmd

Tags: windows, git, shell, cmd, sublimetext2

I have a problem using Git plugin for Sublime text. For every git command I get an error: "Parameter format not correct". Same happens when I use git in cmd. But in cygwin/bash there are no any problems.

Obviously, Sublime text using windows cmd.exe for executing git commands. So I need to force Sublime to use cygwin/bash.

How can I do it? Or are there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont use Sublime, so can't be sure that there is no option for proper configuration of plugin. May be there is one.

But, you can try to force use bash instead of cmd via redefining `COMSPEC` environment variable (thought, running Sublime from batch file). For example

```
SET COMSPEC=c:\git\bin\bash.exe --login -i
start sublime.exe
```

Of course, you may set COMSPEC in system properties (glabally), but I don't recommend this, cause of this may affect other programs...

Comment: thanks for your asnwer. I did it:
  
    `set comspec="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i  
    start sublime_text`  
  
And now, when I use any git command in sublime, I get:  
  
    `Welcome to Git (version 1.7.9-preview20120201)  
    Run 'git help git' to display the help index.  
    Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.  
    sh.exe": /c: is a directory`  
  
What should I do?

Comment: In a different situation and after a git upgrade I got the same error `sh.exe": /c: is a directory`. I could fix it by changing the COMSPEC variable to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. Might not be applicable to this situation, but might be useful to somebody else with this same strange error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set something like...

`,"git_command": "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\git.exe"`

Inside the Git.sublime-settings file in your User Packages/Git folder

Comment: This works, but instead of modifying ```User Packages/Git```, copy ```User Packages/Git/Git.sublime-settings``` to ```User Packages/User/Git.sublime-settings``` and make your edit there.  Do this so if there is an update to the Git plugin you don't loose your change.